# alternative methods are used for location searches on dating sites other than quadtrees?

Tags: search, quadtree

I got quadtrees working on a swingers site I have been building. But I wondered what other equally powerful approaches there would be to searching based on location.
I havn't bee able to find much about this.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why quadtrees aren't appropriate here and why you're looking for alternatives? And can you elaborate more on your requirements?

Comment: they are appropriate. I was just interested in why there is such a lack of literature on the internet about this. I already built it all and it works great:

Comment: But I am interested in alternatives if there are any.

Comment: client side code I wrote which does most of the work: http://textuploader.com/ddflj.

Answer (score 0):

Have look at the bottom of the [Wikipedia Quadtree page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). Other commonly used multi-dimensional indexes are kd-Trees and R-Trees. There are also more specialized depending on what you need to do.
R*Trees (RStarTree) and kdb-Trees are, for example, good for aligning them with a page size so they can be efficiently stored on disk.